# Cut off all non-numeric values in a column

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way in Excel or in VBA to filter the cell by his character and then insert it into a separate column?

For example, my data looks like this:

```
A3200,12 
AB2000,32 
-300,34 
32567,32A 
6745,21AB 
500+
```

And I want that the result be like this:

```
Column A
3200,12
2000,23
300,34
32567,32
6745,21
500

Column B
A
AB
-
A
AB
+
```

So is there a way to go thorugh each cell and cut off all non-numeric values out of These and copy them into another column?

Comment: see [link](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/isnumeric.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to create UDF (User-Difined Function).

Place 2 following functions into a VBA Module:

```
Function Digits(s As String) As String
     With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
        .Pattern = "[^0-9,]"
        .Global = True
        Digits = .Replace(s, "")
    End With
End Function

Function NonDigits(s As String) As String
   With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
      .Pattern = "[0-9,]"
      .Global = True
      NonDigits = .Replace(s, "")
   End With
End Function
```

To use these functions: if you data is in cell A1, just type formula in cell B1

```
=Digits(A1)
```

and in cell C1:

```
=NonDigits(A1)
```

The first will return your data as text containing digits only. To convert it to a number, use VALUE function.

The second returns your data without any digits.

Comment: Thank you so much! This works like a charm. My only problem is, that with "=Digits()" the function also deletes the comma and with "=NonDigits()" he keeps them. Is there a possibility to change that?

Comment: fixed it. Be careful with the minus sign  if you have any negative numbers.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you! This worked so good! Is there a place where I can read something about UDFs? Because, I actually don't really understand how this function submit the given result. Greetings